# A definite integral from 0 to 1 returns a value less than 0 iff there exists c in $[0,1]$ such that $f(c) < 0$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

The exact problem:
Let $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous with $f(x) \leq 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. We want to show that $\int_0^1 f(x) dx < 0 \iff \exists c \in [0,1]$ s. t. $f(c) < 0$.

For the forward direction I have the following:
Suppose $\int_0^1 f(x)dx < 0$ but for all $c \in [0,1] f(c) \geq 0$. Then if $f(c) = 0$ for all $c \in [0,1]$ then $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = 0$, contradiction.

I am having trouble with the other direction though:
Suppose there exists $c \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c) < 0$. Then ...

Comment: The idea is that if $f(c)<0$ for some $c$, then $f(x)<0$ on a neighborhood of $c$ by continuity, which is enough to make the integral $<0$.

Comment: Try showing that $f$ is smaller than $f(c)/2$ on an interval of positive length using continuity. Then use monotonicity of the integral operator.

Comment: Fun fact: if you replace continuity of $f$ with just Riemann integrability then this fact is still true but it becomes much harder to prove (you need the notion of measure 0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c\in [0,1]$ and $f(c)<0$ there exists a closed interval $J\subset [0,1]$ with positive length $|J|$, with $c\in J$, such that $$\forall x\in J\; (|f(x)-f(c)|\leq |f(c)|/2).$$ This is because $f$ is continuous. $$\text {Hence }\quad \forall x\in J\;(f(x)\leq f(c)/2).$$ Now $\int_{[0,1] \backslash J}f(x)dx\leq 0$ because $f$ is never positive. Therefore $$\int_0^1f(x)dx=\int_Jf(x)dx+\int_{[0,1]\backslash J}f(x)dx\leq \int_Jf(x)dx\leq $$ $$\leq \int_J(f(c)/2)dx=|J|f(c)/2<0.$$